# Disable Cached JSON response on frequent browser calls to django view

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, browser, python-requests

In my django app, I use views to call the django method I want to test under development.

When I call my view visiting the mapped url localhost:8000/do_something, twice, it'll return me the cached JSON response and won't process the requests again which destroys my usage of testing the code.

I'm aware that it's definitely not the best practice, but I'd just like to work with it, so following are the things I tried:

Clearing the browser cache(In chrome, IE and firefox, all three)

Restarting the server

It ultimately clears the cache in 2-3 restarts, and the view makes the method calls again instead of just returning the cached JSON response.
 
I'm sure it's a preference or some setting, would be glad if someone could resolve me with this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding thee **@never_cache** django decorator to my views. e.g.

```
@never_cache
def do_somethig(request):
return JsonResponse({"Tested":"OK"})
```